# Where can I find a tsc errors list?

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to use tsc to automatically generate typescript declaration files for some existing javascript code. The typescript compiler is giving me some errors that I don't understand (TS9005 in this case). Is there a reference list of all the error codes generated by tsc and explanations on what they mean somewhere? It would be rather handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of diagnostic messages can be found in [`src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json) in the TypeScript repository. The file is structured like this:

```json
{
    "Unterminated string literal.": {
        "category": "Error",
        "code": 1002
    },
    "Identifier expected.": {
        "category": "Error",
        "code": 1003
    },
    "'{0}' expected.": {
        "category": "Error",
        "code": 1005
    },
    "A file cannot have a reference to itself.": {
        "category": "Error",
        "code": 1006
    },
    // etc...
}
```

However, there is no list that I know of with explanations.

---

TS9005 (`Declaration emit for this file requires using private name '{0}'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.`) means that a JS file is exporting something that has a non-exported type. For example:

`foo.d.ts`

```ts
interface Foo {
  foo: number
}
declare function foo(): Foo
export = foo
```

`bar.js`

```js
// @ts-check
module.exports = require('./foo')()
```

TypeScript cannot create a declaration file for `bar.js` because the export has the type `Foo`, which is not exported from `foo.d.ts`. You can fix this by adding a type declaration for the export:

`bar.js`

```js
// @ts-check
/** @type {{foo: number}} */
module.exports = require('./foo')()
```